# Background worker update progress freezes datagridview

Tags: windows, winforms, backgroundworker

I am trying to write an application to get a list a users in various AD groups and display them in a datagrid on a form.
When a button on my form is clicked it fires a background worker which calls a method to get the user list for an AD group.
The background worker returns a data table and the background worker completed method sets the data grid data source to the data table and everything works OK.
The problem comes when I try to use the background worker progress changed method to update the data grid as each data table column is filled in. It works OK while the background worker is running but when it finishes the grid and the form becomes unresponsive for several minutes.
I'm struggling to figure out why this is.

code example:

```
backroundWorker_DoWork(.........)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;

    //Get datatable from argument
    DataTable dt2 = e.Argument as DataTable

    //get list of AD groups to check
    for (int i = 0; i > dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        columnName = dt2.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        groupName = dt2.Rows[i][1].ToString();

        //Call Method to get users from nested AD groups
        GetADUsers(groupName)

        //Add users returned from above method to DataTable dt
        //..........


        //Send DataTable to Report Progress
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, dt);

    }


    e.Result = dt;

 }


backroundWorker_ProgressChanged(..........)
{
    DataTable dt = e.UserState as DataTable;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}


backroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(..........)
{
    DataTable dt = e.UserState as DataTable;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In RunWorkerCompled() event handler, you should use e.Result instead of e.UserState i.e. your code should be like:

```
DataTable dt = e.Result as DataTable,
```

As a practice before reading the result in RunWorkerCompleted event, you should also check for error using e.Error != null syntax, see the complete ComputeFibonacci example using background worker component in the below MSDN link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx